Find Me App notifications
If I share a notification from my iPad with a family member, does it shows a notification on my phone or in an email? Meaning if I program find me from my IPad to share with someone…. Will a notification pop on my phone!?

When you share a notification or location from your iPad with a family member using the Find My app, the notification won't automatically appear on your iPhone or email. Instead, it will alert the recipient on their own device. However, any updates or alerts regarding your location settings will sync across all devices connected to the same Apple ID, but this doesn't mean you'll receive a direct notification on your phone.

Can you add a link to Apple's documentation on this?
